# HorizontalScrollView issue

Tags: android, android-layout, horizontalscrollview

I want to make a news ticker using a `HorizontalScrollView`. As a first step, I am simply trying out the `HorizontalScrollView` which contains only a `Button` as the content. I want the `Button` to fill the entire screen and the `Button`'s text to be centered. But so far, the `Button` is stuck on the left side. Here is the code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to solve this problem?

Try to use the `fillViewport` attribute on the `HorizontalScrollView`:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```